# Hibernate do not read the commited changes by another transaction on READ_COMMITED isolation level

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm learning about locking and isolation levels along with Hibernate 5 and I'm trying to do some tests on isolation levels; I want to test the **READ_COMMITED** isolation level, but the result is not the expected one. Long story short:

I set the isolation level on MySql (version 8).

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

I have a Dummy entity model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table
@Entity
public class Dummy {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String value;

    private int countDown;
}
```

And the following test:

```
@Test
public void testReadCommitted() {
    doInJPA(entityManagerFactorySupplier, entityManager1 -> {
        doInJPA(entityManagerFactorySupplier, entityManager2 -> {
            Dummy victim = entityManager2.find(Dummy.class, id);
            victim.setValue("Changed by T2");

            entityManager1.clear();
            Dummy beforeT2Commit = entityManager1.find(Dummy.class, id);
            assertEquals(beforeT2Commit.getValue(), "Default");
        });
        entityManager1.clear();
        Dummy afterT2Commit = entityManager1.find(Dummy.class, id);
        // Here I expect to have the new value but for some reason I receive the old one
        assertEquals(afterT2Commit.getValue(), "Changed by T2");
    });
}
```

Relevant dependecies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Persistence unit config

```
<persistence-unit name="DBCONFIG">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>edu.example.test.entities.Dummy</class>
    <class>edu.example.test.entities.lock.OptimisticVersionDummy</class>
    <class>edu.example.test.entities.lock.OptimisticDirtyDummy</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                  value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_test"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="100"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

From logs I can see that a SELECT is triggered after the transaction from entityManager2 was committed and closed.
Also while I'm debugging I can see that the row was changed into DB after the commit, but even so I'm receiving the old result from entityManager1 transaction.
I do not use any level 2 cache and also I clear the persistence context from entityManager1 before reading again.

logs:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        dummy0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        dummy0_.countDown as countdow2_0_0_,
        dummy0_.value as value3_0_0_ 
    from
        Dummy dummy0_ 
    where
        dummy0_.id=?
2023-Mar-06 10:32:19 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [773]
2023-Mar-06 10:32:19 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([countdow2_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [0]
2023-Mar-06 10:32:19 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([value3_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Default]
Hibernate: 
    select
        dummy0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        dummy0_.countDown as countdow2_0_0_,
        dummy0_.value as value3_0_0_ 
    from
        Dummy dummy0_ 
    where
        dummy0_.id=?
2023-Mar-06 10:32:19 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [773]
2023-Mar-06 10:32:19 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([countdow2_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [0]
2023-Mar-06 10:32:19 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([value3_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Default]
Hibernate: 
    update
        Dummy 
    set
        countDown=?,
        value=? 
    where
        id=?
2023-Mar-06 10:32:22 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
2023-Mar-06 10:32:22 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Changed by T2]
2023-Mar-06 10:32:22 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [773]
Hibernate: 
    select
        dummy0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        dummy0_.countDown as countdow2_0_0_,
        dummy0_.value as value3_0_0_ 
    from
        Dummy dummy0_ 
    where
        dummy0_.id=?
2023-Mar-06 10:32:22 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [773]
2023-Mar-06 10:32:22 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([countdow2_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [0]
2023-Mar-06 10:32:22 AM [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([value3_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Default]
```

**UPDATE_1: WITH SOLUTION**
The URL for DB connection has to specify the isolation level

```
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_test?sessionVariables=transaction_isolation='READ-COMMITTED'"/>
```

**UPDATE_2**
Isolation levels are working different from DB to DB and some phenomenas migh not occur. For example

READ_UNCOMMITTED:

- Dirty Read on MySQL occur
- Dirty Read on PostgreSQL DO NOT occur

Comment: `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED` - how do you apply that? that command has session scope, so you need to issue it every time when new JDBC connection has created.

Comment: I looked over the docs from mysql again and I set the isolation to global SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
How I did was to set on SESSION so I guess that only he first session will have that isolation level.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov should I  trigger an SQL statement with SET SESSION... everytime I start a transaction ?

Comment: That depends on how you are going to manage jdbc connections, typically if you assume that is a property of particular application, then connection pool should be responsible for that (for example, we use HikariCP and it has `connectionInitSql` option), in your case (you manage JDBC via PU) I would reconned to add `?sessionVariables=transaction_isolation='READ-COMMITTED'` to JDBC URL.

Comment: I understand now. So the isolation level is set by the PU or by a ConnectionPool and is set as application scope and not per session/transaction. Cool. Thanks. Could you write it as an answer in order to mark it as the correct answer ?

Comment: `and not per session/transaction` - actually, I meant **default** isolation level for particular application. There are no barriers to set isolation level per transaction, for example, `spring` framework does allow to do that, however without `spring` that could be challenging: in pure HBN case you can change it via `entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class).connection().setTransactionIsolation(...)`, but you must to return previous isolation level back upon transaction completion, otherwise you have all chances to poison connection pool.